# Как себя ведет struct в Swift, если в структуре есть переменная класса?

Tags: ios, swift

Как себя ведет struct в Swift, если в структуре есть переменная класса?

У нас есть примерно такой код:

```
class SomeClass {
... // какие-то переменные, думаю, это не важно
}

struct SomeStruct {
    var someClass: SomeClass
}
```

Я знаю что структура лежит в стеке, а класс в куче.

Но где будет располагаться структура, если структура будет держать сильную ссылку на класс? Структура будет всё равно лежать в стеке со ссылкой на класс или уже будет лежать в куче как класс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае, структура будет так же лежать в стеке, а класс будет находиться в куче. В данном случае на стеке будет лежать лишь указатель на экземпляр класса, а его содержимое – остаётся в куче.

Однако важно понимать, что компилятор в разных случаях может помещать структуры и классы как на стек, так и на кучу, в целях оптимизации.

Помещение классов на стек называется Stack Promotion и применяется в тех случаях, когда компилятор обладает информацией о том, что экземпляру класса достаточно семантики структур (например, он не покидает тела функции).

Обратная операция (помещение структур в кучу) применяется во избежание лишнего копирования неизменяемых структур, например, при передаче в качестве параметра в функцию.

Таким образом, правильный ответ на вопрос "зависит от ситуации", но если без всяких оптимизаций – должно быть как в первом абзаце ответа.